# Simple Website to show WMS with Openlayers

Tags: openlayers-2, openlayers, wms, web-mapping

i want a simple website to show a WMS and want to use Openlayers. 
I started with Quick Start from Openlayers newest version, but got errors. 
So i took an old workspace (openlayers version 2) and edited this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>OpenLayers Demo</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.3.1/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
    <style type="text/css">
      html, body, #basicMap {
          width: 600px;
          height: 600px;
          margin: 10;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="http://www.openlayers.org/api/OpenLayers.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js?features=requestAnimationFrame,Element.prototype.classList,URL"></script>
  </head>
  <body onload="init();">
    <div id="basicMap"></div>
        <script>
      function init() {}
        map = new OpenLayers.Map("basicMap");
        map.addLayer(new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM());
        var mv = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS( 
            "WMS MV",
            "https://www.geodaten-mv.de/dienste/alkis_wms?", 
            {
                layers: 'adv_alkis_flurstuecke', 
                version:"1.1.1", 
                format:"image/png"
            }, 
            {isBaseLayer: false} 
        );  
        map.addLayers([mv]);
        map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(11.5043,53.594) // Center of the map
          .transform(
            new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"), // transform from WGS 1984
            new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:3857") // to Spherical Mercator Projection
          ),
          16 // Zoom level
        );
        map.addControl( new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher() );
        var ctrl_1 = new OpenLayers.Control.MousePosition({displayProjection: 'EPSG:4326'});
        map.addControl( ctrl_1 );
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

So i got an little div with a map, but without the WMS.

I tested the WMS on this [enter link description here](https://www.geoportal-mv.de/portal/Geowebdienste/Fachthemen/Tourismus_und_Freizeit)

THE URL for WMS: https://www.geodaten-mv.de/dienste/alkis_wms?request=GetCapabilities&SERVICE=WMS&version=1.3.0

What am I doing wrong?  I don't have to use Version 2 from OpenLayers! 
I need a simple local website to Show WMS as layer. 
Maybe there is a problem with projection...

```
[1]: http://gis.ibbeck.de/ginfo/apps/OLExamples/OL212/wms_example/add_WMSlayer.asp
```

---

Another try with Openlayers 4 and WMS from this site (https://www.geoportal-mv.de/portal/Geowebdienste/Fachthemen/Tourismus_und_Freizeit):

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="de">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.4.2/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
<style>
  .map {
    height: 600px;
    width: 800px;
  }
</style>
<script src="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.4.2/build/ol.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<title>OpenLayers example</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2>My Map</h2>
<div id="map" class="map"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var map = new ol.Map({
    target: 'map',
    layers: [
      new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.OSM()
      }),
      new ol.layer.Tile({
          extent: [-13884991, 2870341, -7455066, 6338219],
          source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
            url: 'https://ahocevar.com/geoserver/wms',
            params: {'LAYERS': 'topp:states', 'TILED': true},
            serverType: 'geoserver'
          })
        }),
    new ol.layer.Tile({
      extent: [33290156, 5948802, 33369558, 6001737],
      source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
        url: 'https://www.umweltkarten.mv-regierung.de/script/mv_a2_landplan_wms.php?',
        params: {
            'LAYERS': 't2_boden1',
            'FORMAT': 'image/png',
            'VERSION': '1.1.1',
            'SRS': 'EPSG:5650',
            'WIDTH': '300',
            'HEIGHT': '200'
        }
      })
    })
    ],
    view: new ol.View({
      center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([11.5, 53.9]), 
      zoom: 11
    })
  });
</script>
```

The WMS isn't visible on the map, the Image from WMS isn't empty. 
Maybe, anyone else can help!?

Comment: "but got errors" what errors exactly?

Comment: The layer you selected is not available at all scales, are you saying it doesn't appear when you zoom in to the visible scale?  In QGIS I have data at location 12.660055,53.881147, what if you zoom in to that location?

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass some parameters to WMS service, thats all required.

For example

```
https://www.geodaten-mv.de/dienste/alkis_wms?request=GetMap&SERVICE=WMS&version=1.3.0&CRS=EPSG%3A3857&BBOX=1137794.83221942,6967662.42046048,1658813.45554506,7332932.41531642&WIDTH=573&HEIGHT=662&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&TRANSPARENT=true
```

I passed CRS,BBOX,WIDTH,HEIGHT,FORMAT and TRANSPARENT parameters and got an image but its empty. Also your request parameter must be "GetMap". You can pass right parameters like this and try to get an image.

Openlayers pass some parameters automatically but you have to check projection and bbox values. I am working an example with your WMS service, if I completed, I will add here.

Comment: look at my second post, please

Comment: @ben_GI89 can you request this wms manually? with browser or etc.

Comment: i can request this WMS and got xml

Comment: @ben_GI89 what was the XML you got, is it an error message?